# How to solve XAMPP PHPMyAdmin 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am using Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2s PHP/7.1.32 my phpmyadmin is suddenly not accessible its shows following error:

> Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested
>   directory. There is either no index document or the directory is
>   read-protected.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

I had tried everything but still not able to get it right

Comment: Is this answered your question? https://superuser.com/a/201868/636993

Comment: "I had tried everything" — please tell us a bit more about what exactly you've tried that hasn't worked, that way we can avoid making incorrect suggestions.

Comment: Any further hints in the webserver error log? What is the URL you're trying to load? If it's something like `https://localhost/phpmyadmin/` have you also tried adding  index.php to the end as suggested by the error message (`https://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php`)?

Answer (score 1):

I had some error like this once, I just edit the `httpd-xampp.conf` from `Require local` to `Require all granted` in the `LocationMatch` tag. Or configure the `http-vhosts.conf` Directory tag to

```
<Directory>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
     AllowOverride none
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Doing that is insecure. Anyone from anywhere in your network (or anyone from anywhere if port forwarding is done) can access your phpmyadmin. XAMPP also allows you to login without password to root. Do not do that except when you are not connected to a network, never. You are misleading them. (I am not being rude)

Answer (score 1):

Go to below file

```
C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf
```

Then go to Directory tag as below:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
```

and then in the Directory tag change as below:

From

```
Require local
```

To

```
Require all granted
```

`Restart the Xampp`

That's it!